# PHPs imagecolorset() is ignored

Tags: php, image

It seems that imagecolorclosest gets ignored (PHP 5.6), i.e. I have an image output w/o replaced colors. I hoped to replace every #f2f2f2 - #f4f4f4 gray with #fff.

Do I miss something?

```
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg ($path);
    @unlink($path);

    $index = imagecolorclosest ( $im,  243,243,243 );
    imagecolorset($im,$index,255,255,255);
    $index = imagecolorclosest ( $im,  242,242,242 );
    imagecolorset($im,$index,255,255,255);
    $index = imagecolorclosest ( $im,  241,241,241 );
    imagecolorset($im,$index,255,255,255); // SET NEW COLOR

    imagejpeg($im, $path, $iQuality ); // If I set iQuality=10 for testing I get a horrible quality image, so this part works.
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: @Martin thanks, unfortunately it's not about cache. I can switch back and forth between iQuality 10 & 100 and see the quality difference. Hence the image gets created.

Comment: have you copied the example on [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorset.php)? That has a lot more colour allocation code than you have....

Comment: I copied the exact example, with still no color replacement result. I can still confirm that those function do save the image and alter the quality while completely ignoring the color part.